# Why acceptParamNames is not working for the following value in Struts 2

Tags: regex, struts2, ognl

I want to send values from JSP to struts Bean. In Bean I have one map which value I want to set. It is working for all other key. but when the key name is like below it is not accepting.

KeyName: `Proximus Voice Continuity.CUSTOMERID.value`

in my `struts.xml` I have below configuration:

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="params">
    <!-- For maps to work -->
    <param name="acceptParamNames">[a-zA-Z0-9\.\]\[\(\)_'\s"/-]+</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Comment: Why do you modify `acceptParamNames` in the first place? Not clear what key name is.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your regex pattern and it matches the key specified. But your key is composed by other keys that can't be used in OGNL expression.

If you remove the `acceptParamNames` parameter from the interceptor your key doesn't match the list of default patterns.

This regex pattern is used by default

```
\w+((\.\w+)|(\[\d+\])|(\(\d+\))| (\['(\w|[\u4e00-\u9fa5])+'\])|(\('(\w|[\u4e00-\u9fa5])+'\)))*
```

If you remove spaces in key names then it matches this pattern.